# Blowup of $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ and a sheaf computation

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $Y_1=Y_2=\mathbb{P}^1$, $Y=Y_1\times Y_2$, $p_i:Y\rightarrow Y_i$, $i=1,2$ be a canonnical projections and $\pi:X\rightarrow Y$ be a blowup of $Y$ in a finite set of points. How to compute $(p_2\pi)_*(p_1\pi)^*(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1))$?

I tried to use a projection formula in the following way
$$(p_2\pi)_*(p_1\pi)^*(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1))\cong p_{2*}\pi_*\pi^*(p_1^*(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1)))\cong p_{2*}p_1^*(\mathcal{O}_{Y_1}(1))\cong\mathcal{O}_{Y_2}(1),$$
but the answer seems not to be correct.

Comment: (I deleted my incorrect answer so somebody else can answer.)

Comment: I have another silly comment. Are you sure that $(p_2)_{*}p_1^{*}\mathscr{O}_{Y_1}(1)=\mathscr{O}_{Y_2}(1)$? I think it is instead $\mathscr{O}_{Y_2}^2$ (check on open affines)...

Comment: Yes, you are right.